# Laplace transform of the Weibull distribution for $\kappa>1$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, laplace-transform, moment-generating-functions, renewal-processes

In the [Wikipedia article on the Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution), the moment generating function is given:

$$g(s) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{s^n \lambda^n}{n!} \Gamma\left(1+\frac{n}{\kappa}\right )$$

However, it is only defined for $\kappa \geq 1$. Doesn't seem like anything will break here for $\kappa < 1$. And that is an interesting case where it has a decreasing hazard rate. So, why can't I apply this formula for $\kappa < 1$?

Comment: I think that the sum will fail to converge in that case, and the integral representation must be used.

Comment: Thanks! What is the integral representation? The definition itself?

Comment: For $\kappa<1$ it looks like the MGF just doesn't exist, so you have enough decay that all finite moments exist but the whole MGF does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the Weibull pdf is defined as
$$f:\mathbb R_+\to \mathbb R_+~~,~~f(x;\lambda,\kappa)=\frac{\kappa}{\lambda}(x/\lambda)^{\kappa-1}\exp\big((-x/\lambda)^\kappa\big)$$
WLOG let's consider $\lambda=1$:
$$\phi(x;k):=f(x,1,k)=k x^{k-1}\exp(-x^k)$$
The moment generating function is defined as a sort of Laplace transform:
$$g(s;k):=(\mathcal Lf)(-s;k)=\int_0^\infty e^{sx}\phi(x;k)\mathrm dx$$
This integral is
$$k\int_0^\infty x^{k-1}\exp(sx-x^k)\mathrm dx$$
But what happens if $k<1$? Well, then actually the integral **fails to converge**, since the argument of the exponential function $sx-x^k$ will grow without bound, since $x^1$ grows faster than $x^{1/2}$, e.g. So our integrand looks like
$$\frac{ \exp(O(x^1))}{x^{1-k}}$$
And of course the exponential growth in the numerator beats the power growth in the denominator. As for the sum representation, it is simply a Taylor series. By Taylor's theorem we know that in some neighborhood of $s=0$ that
$$g(s;k)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\mathrm D^{n}g)(0;k)}{n!}x^n$$
And one can see from the Leibniz integral rule that
$$(\mathrm D^ng)(0;k)=k\int_0^\infty x^{k+n-1}\exp(-x^k)\mathrm dx$$
With a change of variable (i.e $z=x^k$) one can see that this is just
$$(\mathrm D^ng)(0;k)=k\int_0^\infty x^{k+n-1}\exp(-x^k)\mathrm dx=\Gamma(1+n/k)$$
Which gives us
$$g(s;k)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{s^n}{n!}\Gamma(1+n/k)$$

Comment: Thanks. So it looks like the Laplace transform, which is obtained by replacing $s$ with $-s$ should converge for $\kappa<1$? Because that will cause the exponent to decrease rapidly instead of increase?

Comment: @RohitPandey Technically the MGF "exists" if the expectation defining it is finite for $s$ on some open neighborhood of zero, so just slapping in a $-s$ does not fix the problem. Basically the point here is that the Weibull PDF for $\kappa<1$ decays faster than any rational function at infinity but does not decay faster than any exponential function at infinity.

Comment: @RohitPandey The Laplace transform is defined as
$$(\mathcal L f)(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}f(x)\mathrm dx$$
So,
$$(\mathcal Lf)(-s)=\int_0^\infty e^{sx}f(x)\mathrm dx$$
So no, it will not converge for $\kappa<1$.

Comment: @K.defaoite The point Rohit was making was based on the MGF which doesn't have the minus sign in there, but again it doesn't matter, because the MGF has to be finite on a neighborhood of zero for it to exist.